# Biblatex changed the appended letter's format for same author/year?

Tags: biblatex, biber

For some years, I've been using the following biblatex configuration in my LaTeX class:

```
\RequirePackage[
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  dashed=false,
  maxnames=1,
  maxbibnames=6,
  minbibnames=6,
  backend=biber,
  uniquename=init,
  giveninits=true,
  bibliography=totoc
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {et al.}}
```

Today I compiled a document with `biber` and the most recent TexLive version 2017 and was amazed that citing two different articles from the same author in the same year resulted in the format `(Author 2017[a])` and `(Author 2017[b])` rather than `(Author 2017a)` and `(Author 2017b)` as it used to.

Did I miss a change here or was the former style never intended to look like that? How would I have to change the configuration in order to remove the square brackets around the appended letters for articles of the same year and author?

Comment: There should be no intentional change here. There was https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/603 a while ago that arose in very specific situations. The problem will be fixed in the upcoming version 3.8 of `biblatex`. Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) so we can investigate your problem in more detail. We will need to see the offending `.bib` entries as well as the full document setup.

Comment: Note that in new versions of `biblatex` `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` should be `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`. And that `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {et al.}}` should ideally be `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}`.

Comment: thank you moewe, I'll provide an MWE as soon as possible.

Comment: moewe, thank you again for the hints. Your linked github issue pointed to the other question at texwelt.de and I figured out I had the exact same problem: The `date` attribute of the reference was missing. As a fallback, biblatex seems to use `urldate` but doesn't treat it exactly the same as `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This was a bug that has been resolved in version 3.8 of `biblatex`. If you still have this problem, check your version and do an update.

As confirmed in the comments, this is the issue described in "[biblatex: Eliminieren der Klammer um Kleinbuchstaben hinter Jahreszahl](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/20499/biblatex-eliminieren-der-klammer-um-kleinbuchstaben-hinter-jahreszahl)" over at TeXwelt.de

A simplified MWE would be

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Grundprinzipien,
    author = {FSC},
    title = {Die Regeln für den Wald. 10 Grundsätze -- weltweit},
    url = {http://www.fsc-deutschland.de/de-de/der-fscr/prinzipien},
    urldate = {2017-07-31}
}

@report{FSC2017,
    title = {Facts and figures},
    type = {Report},
    institutions = {FSC International},
    date = {2017-07-04},
    url = {https://ic.fsc.org/file-download.facts-figures-july-2017.a-2020.pdf},
    urldate = {2017-07-12},
    author = {FSC}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Grundprinzipien,FSC2017}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE before fix]

The issue was reported https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/603 with a suggested fix https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/604. The problem should be resolved in version 3.8.

Until then you can add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{%
  \iffieldnums{labelyear}
    {\mknumalph{#1}}
    {\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}}
```

to your preamble.
Upon which you will get
[image: MWE after fix]
as expected.